# Highcharts date off by one day

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm passing in milliseconds for the x-axis and then defining the x-axis as:

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
```

However, Highcharts seems to be not getting the exact date on the x-axis but is instead off by one day. To illustrate, hover over any of the bars (fiddle at the bottom of this post) and you will see what Highcharts interprets the day as but then click any of them and I have an on-click event to alert you what the actual date is supposed to be. Notice how it is off by one day.

Is this a known bug in Highcharts? Any workarounds?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hohenheim/j8cTE/33/

Comment: I've had similar issues with HighCharts.  I think I ended up just doing categories instead of datetime.  Good luck.

Comment: I have the same issue, I convert my dates to strtotime($date) * 1000 but it screws me over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is format/consider for UTC. Highcharts default is UTC (0). (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global) if you change to this:

```
function appendAds(date1) {
   alert(new Date(date1).toUTCString());
   $('#tableTitle').html("<u>Info for " + timeConverter(date1) + ":</u>");
   ...
}
```

(fiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/j8cTE/34/

You will see that it shows correct date with that "toUTCString()" added. You will likely want to convert it to something more pleasant to read, but remember that you will have to keep UTC in mind if you don't use "toUTCString()".

UPDATE:
I wanted to explain that I used "toUTCString()" since it was quick and something I knew off the top of my head. This method wouldn't work for all things, such as further down in your appendAds function since it is a string. To explain UTC and date formatting, parsing and manipulation in full would be too much for this post. But I will try to go over a few key points when dealing with dates on the web. Also, please see MDN for other date info (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

If you need accurate information and/or logic for dates, you will need to know the date format you get (from server, database, etc...) - whether it is UTC or not, for example. Then you need to consider if it needs to be manipulated for display (such as for the viewers browser's timezone). And finally, if that date is being used internally, you need to consider if, when, and where you need to convert it once again (as appropriate).

Comment: Hmm, could you explain further? Why does `toUTCString()` give the right date? whereas just `new date` does not? Don't they represent the same thing?

I found another workround that uses `useUTC : false` as a highchart option, this changes the Highcharts tooltip date to match the date I have. What is the difference?