# Highcharts: Month seems to be off by one day

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts, momentjs

I have a highcharts which appears to show one day too many in the x-axis. This occurs when I set endOnTick to true, and if I instead set endOnTick to false the x-axis seems to be wrongly aligned (not in center, as if there were to be another tick that's supposed to be there). As you can see from my fiddle I am using moment.js to set the min/max dates, but startOf('month') works fine and endOf('month') should show the last day of the month, shouldn't it? I've tried to set UTC to false as you can see in the fiddle, but that didn't work. I am sorry if I'm missing something obvious here but I am quite new to both Highcharts and moment.js so please be patient with me :) Any tips would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    var myChart = $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: moment().format('MMMM') + ' ' + moment().format('YYYY')
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'DATE'
                },
                type: 'datetime',
                endOnTick: true,
                tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%e'
                },
                min: moment().startOf('month'),
                max: moment().endOf('month')
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                max: 4,
                min: 1,
                allowDecimals: false,
                tickInterval: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'circle'
                    },
                    animation: false
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 6, 25), 3.2],
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 7, 1), 2],
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 7, 5), 1.75],
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 7, 10), 2.4],
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 7, 15), 2.7],
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 7, 23), 2.3],
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 7, 28), 3],
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 7, 31), 2]
                ]
            }, {
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 7, 1), 3],
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 7, 5), 2.75],
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 7, 10), 3.2],
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 7, 15), 2.3],
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 7, 23), 3.3],
                    [Date.UTC(2017, 7, 28), 1.5]
                ]
        }],
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
        })
    }
    )
```

And here is a fiddle with the same code: https://jsfiddle.net/t0eeab8b/1/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766341/highcharts-date-off-by-one-day

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts date off by one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766341/highcharts-date-off-by-one-day)